# How to use ORDER BY in MySQL using variable SET

Tags: mysql, variables, filter, sql-order-by, rows

This query for calculate sum `p_quantity <= 21000` for `p_description`. The query works but when you add `ORDER BY p_reference` show all rows

I tried to add `ORDER BY` like this:

```
SET @runtot:=0;
SELECT p_id, p_description, (@runtot := @runtot + p_quantity) AS runningTotal
FROM product_table
WHERE @runtot + p_quantity <= 21000 AND p_description = 'product_1' ORDER BY p_reference ASC
```

This is the code to create Product table:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `product_table` (
  `p_id` int(11) PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL,
  `p_description` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `p_reference` varchar(25) NOT NULL,
  `p_location` varchar(25) NOT NULL,
  `p_quantity` int(11) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;

INSERT INTO `product_table` (`p_id`, `p_description`, `p_reference`, `p_location`, `p_quantity`) VALUES
  (1, 'Product_1', '1A00001', 'AP07', 7000),
  (2, 'Product_1', '1A00001', 'AF05', 6000),
  (3, 'Product_1', '1A00233', 'DS07', 7000),
  (4, 'Product_1', '1A00233', 'SD10', 5000),
  (5, 'Product_1', '1A00001', 'YB12', 7000),
  (6, 'Product_1', '1A00001', 'AN01', 7000),
  (7, 'Product_1', '1A00001', 'AP04', 7000),
  (8, 'Product_1', '1A00245', 'AP01', 7000),
  (9, 'Product_1', '1A00001', 'QD01', 7000),
  (10, 'Product_1', '1A00001', 'SC01', 7000);
```

Comment: I don't understand the question. What are you trying to order by? It looks to me that you are using ORDER BY in your posted query, what is the issue with that?

Comment: When you add ORDER BY p_reference show all rows and p_quantity > 21000, But without the addition ORDER BY p_reference, the total p_quantity <= 21000

Comment: This problem is harder than what it looks like. In fact, I am voting your question up for giving me a challenge :)  Please check my answer below

Comment: Im using this query in file php but I have problem, Warning: mysql_fetch_assoc() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in C:\xampp\htdocs\TEST\test.php on line 16

Answer (score 0):

Because you didn't select `p_reference` in the query. Try,

```
SET @runtot:=0;
SELECT p_id, p_description, **p_reference**, (@runtot := @runtot + p_quantity) AS runningTotal
FROM product_table
WHERE @runtot + p_quantity <= 21000 AND p_description = 'product_1'
ORDER BY p_reference ASC;
```

Comment: This will make no difference. The issue here is when to order the records

Answer (score 0):

I tried this query but show all rows and `p_quantity > 21000`:

```
SELECT p_id, p_description, p_reference, (@runtot := @runtot + p_quantity) AS runningTotal
FROM product_table
WHERE @runtot + p_quantity <= 21000 AND p_description = 'product_1'
ORDER BY p_reference ASC;
```

and this query without `ORDER BY` show `p_quantity <=21000`:

```
SELECT p_id, p_description, p_reference, (@runtot := @runtot + p_quantity) AS runningTotal
FROM product_table
WHERE @runtot + p_quantity <= 21000 AND p_description = 'product_1';
```

Comment: you should check my answer below.

Comment: Is this an answer or an addition to your question? If it's not an answer, you should [_edit your question_](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/27335294/edit) to include this information. Only actual answers should posted as answers.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, This problem is harder than what it looks like. In fact, I am voting your question up for posting this question :)

The problem here is when to order your data and when to apply your math.

Think about it for a second. You are adding up the `p_quantity` value to the previous `p_quantity`value

So if we have a list like this

```
Preference  Quantity 
D           7000
B           6000
C           7000
A           1500

7000 is <= 2100 so Row D is selected
7000 + 6000 = 13000 is <= than 21000 so Row B is selected
13000 + 7000 = 20000 is <= 21000 so Row C is selected
20000 + 1500 = 21500 is > 210000 Row A is NOT selected and no other rows will be selected
```

The final rows will be

```
Preference  Quantity 
D           7000
B           6000
C           7000
```

But if we sorted the list by the `Preference` column first and then do the same math

```
Preference  Quantity 
A           1500
B           6000
C           7000
D           7000

1500 is <= 21000 so row A is selected
1500 + 6000 = 7500 is <= 21000 row B is selected
7500 + 7000 = 14500 is <= 21000 row C is selected
14500 + 7000 = 21500 is > 21000 row D is not selected and nothing after will be selected
```

The final list will be

```
Preference  Quantity 
A           1500
B           6000
C           7000
```

The idea here is that the final result set is going to be different depending on position of each row when you do your math.

It get around your problem, first want to sort the list and then run your math :)

The query below should solve your problem and give you the data set that you are looking for

```
SET @runtot=0;
-- second go through the sorted set and run your math
SELECT p_reference, p_id, p_description, (@runtot := @runtot + p_quantity) AS runningTotal
FROM (
    -- First generate a sorted data set
    SELECT p_reference, p_id, p_description, p_quantity
    FROM product_table
    WHERE p_description = 'product_1' AND p_quantity <= 21000
    ORDER BY p_reference
) AS l
WHERE @runtot + p_quantity <= 21000;
```